# event attributes on embed tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, embed

```
<div id='aplayer'></div>
```

js

```
$('#note').click(function() {
$('#aplayer').html("<embed src=" + music + " onended='test();'" + ">");
});

function test(){
    alert ('525');
}
```

audio is playing, but `onended()` doesn't work.
I also tried `onplay` and `onplaying` - without result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use HTML5, you should use the audio tag instead of the embed tag.

A JSfiddle exists here: http://jsfiddle.net/u6dbV/

```
<audio controls="controls" onpause="alert('Paused');" onended="alert('Ended');">
    <source src="http://www.jameshilldigital.net/testpage/borg.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

This method also gets you a ton of awesome usage through the HTML5 Audio Tag's API:

http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

If you're looking for a programmatic example, I have a little audio player here:
https://github.com/daekano/beard/blob/master/app/js/beard.js

Comment: daekano, thanks, but I have about 50 `.mp3` files, and in this case each of them I need to duplicate as `.ogg` !

Comment: Ah, I getcha.
The audio tag supports .mp3 on IE, Chrome, Firefox 21 (on Windows 7+/Android).

Comment: Also, I tried your `jsfiddle` - doesn't work. I have win xp sp3 + chrome

Comment: The audio file doesn't exist. It's an old jsfiddle that I found from a google search.

Comment: ok, thanks anyway. You answer very useful for me so I will accept it as solution, but still wondering what is wrong with my code.